# How to show message if search result is empty?

Tags: angular

Now I have the variable:

```
serachResult = [];
```

Inside temaplte I check:

```
<div *ngIf="serachResult.length == 0">No data</div>
```

The array `serachResult`  is filled only if present the search response.

Problem is that message `No data` is shown always, here if user don't make search request

Comment: You can simply add another boolean to your `div` tag like `isSearch`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`searchResult` is initialized as empty array so even before making search request the condition `*ngIf="serachResult.length == 0"` will resolve as true. That's why `No Data` is shown even if user don't make search request.

You can create another variable `isDisplaySearchResult = false` and set it to true once user make search request.
Your template code will be changed as following -

`<div *ngIf="isDisplaySearchResult && serachResult.length == 0">No data</div>`

Comment: How to use this with template? ` *ngIf="documents?.count > 0 && isDisplaySearchResult; else nodata"` ?

Comment: You can do as following
```<div *ngIf="documents?.count > 0 && isDisplaySearchResult">{{ documents }} or {{ searchResult }}</div>

<div *ngIf="!(documents?.count > 0 && isDisplaySearchResult)">No Data</div>```

Answer (score 0):

Define another variable for showing search result and set it's value to `false`:

```
showResult: boolean = false;
```

When user searched and results are available, change `showResult` value to `true`

And In Your html check if `showResult` is true, then check the `serachResult.length`;

```
<div *ngIf="showResult && serachResult.length == 0">No data</div>
```